# Vertical bar symbol not working in RegExp JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I would like to use the vertical bar symbol "|" inside my last RegExp.

I am using AngularJS 1.5.7. $scope.outputValue is an array which I am converting to string, and implementing 2 different RegExps afterwards:

```
$scope.outputValue  =  $scope.outputValue.toString();
$scope.outputValue  =  $scope.outputValue.replace(/,/g, " | ");
$scope.outputValue  =  $scope
                       .replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9.+=-_\{\}/\\<>?;:"'`!@#$%^&*()\[\]]*$/, '');
```

Now, I know it's not the cleanest thing in the world, but the last RegExp includes all the keyboard characters except the "|" symbol. Without the vertical bar, it's doing the job right ( it removes any character after the last character in a string). E.g. this:

```
var foo = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog   |   \ +   ! ?";
```

becomes this:

```
var foo = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
```

Problem is, as soon as I add the vertical bar inside my last RegExp, replace method does not work. I have tried escaping it before, with "\" symbol but it did not work either. I have also tried other RegExps that would include all the keyboard characters, but had no luck with them either. Is there any way I could modify the existing code since it's already doing the job for me, I just need to inlude the vertical bar somehow?

Thanks, Nenad

Comment: In the `/[^A-Za-z0-9.+=-_\{\}/\\<>?;:"'\`!@#$%^&*()\[\]]*$/` pattern, the hyphen must be put to the end/start of the character class. You may try adding `|` as `\u007C`. Try `/[^A-Za-z0-9.+=_{}\/\\<>?;:"'\`!@#$%^&*()\[\]\u007C-]*$/`

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: It seems like you must escape your backslash like: `\/` it is a regex issue, isn't it? Disclaimer, at least your are not trying to match html with regexp.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro yes it is regex issue. So you're suggesting that I use "\\" escaping instead of "\" escaping?

Comment: In a regex literal, you need to use single slashes to escape special regex metacharacters. Even in the `ng-pattern`, you can use single backslashes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have tried using the \u007C version, did not work...

Comment: Then please provide a fiddle.

Comment: nope @WiktorStribiżew is right. I found an unescaped `/` on your code, that's what I meant.

Comment: What chars/symbols do you want to match and remove?

Comment: @kneles90 to be honest with you your regex doesn't seem to match what you're trying to. For example, this one: `/[^A-Za-z0-9\.]*$/g`; replaces all non-alpha and dots chars at the end of a sequence. So I'm not sure what you are trying to do anymore.

Comment: See my [regex fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/1789FD/1), really, it is strange.

Comment: @Marco I want to remove every character after the last character in the string, and the last character in the string could be any keyboard symbol. The string that I am generating from array is going to add: "|" symbols at the end of the string, and I will need to have it removed.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro check out my previous comment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is quite similar to what I am doing: http://plnkr.co/edit/eBjenGqgo3nbnmQ7XxF1?p=preview   My code is based on that, and it turns an array output into as string, which later on replaces default ',' separators with ' | ' separators. Problem occurs when the last string character gets stuck with an extra   ' | ' separator at the end, that's why I want to target the last character of the string and remove everything after it.

Comment: I do not see where you are using a regex there.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am not using any regex since it's not my Plunkr. Like I said, my code is based on that logic. You can think of an output value generated within Plunkr to be my initial $scope.outputValue that I'm working with later, as described in this post. The logic is 100% the same.